# How do I widen Cinnamon's panel entries?

Tags: gnome-panel, cinnamon

I pack a great deal of information into the status line of terminals and like to be able to see it in the panel, but to see it all, I need Cinnamon to let me make the panel entries a bit wider.  I've already shrunken the font as far as I dare in the cinnamon.css#panel.font-size.  How do I change the default width of panel entries?

Comment: [This related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436612/how-to-widen-window-list-item-boxes-in-cinnamon-gnome-desktop-to-fit) demonstrates how to make the entries wider, though unfortunately not the labels.

Answer (score 4):

I have widened them by a factor of 1.25 in the following way:

```
--- /usr/share/cinnamon/applets/window-list@cinnamon.org/applet.js  2014-12-28 17:30:10.451714782 +0000
+++ /home/mint/.local/share/cinnamon/applets/window-list@des-nerger/applet.js   2014-12-28 07:51:57.610317300 +0000
@@ -637,7 +637,7 @@
         alloc.natural_size = naturalSize;
         [minSize, naturalSize] = this._label.get_preferred_width(forHeight);
    alloc.min_size = alloc.min_size + Math.max(0, minSize - Math.floor(alloc.min_size / 2));
-        alloc.natural_size = 150 * global.ui_scale;
+        alloc.natural_size = 150 * global.ui_scale * 5 / 4;
     },

     _getContentPreferredHeight: function(actor, forWidth, alloc) {
```

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 2):

To get the panel entries to expand to the full width of the bar:

*Preferences > Applets > Window list > Configure*

Check *Window buttons can have different sizes and use the entire space available*.

After a Cinnamon restart, panel entries now expand to display the entire window title if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
.window-list-item-label {
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 12em;     /* <- adjust this value */
    min-width: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything on Cinnamon 1.8.8.

Comment: did not work in cinnamon 2.2