# How to widen "Window List Item" boxes in (Cinnamon) Gnome Desktop to fit?

Tags: themes, gnome-panel, cinnamon, css

I was able to increase the size of GNOME panels that hold the Window List Item boxes by modifying the "width" property of the ".window-list-item-box" CSS class of cinnamon.css (in the Cinnamon desktop), but now the label width has not expanded to fit this.  I tried tweaking the width and paddings of the same class and the window-list-item-label class to no avail... Anyone have any suggestions?  See the picture below for more details.

```
.window-list-item-box {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
        background-gradient-direction: vertical;
        background-gradient-start: rgba(100,100,100,0.5);
        background-gradient-end: rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(80,80,80,0.5);
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
    padding: 1px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    transition-duration: 100;
    width: 400px;
}
```

[image: Widen the text area]

Comment: Are you using mint?

Comment: I tried just increasing the `window-list-item-box` width this way, but it messes with the size-compression logic when two many entries appear - so make sure it works for you.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to hack this functionality into the code of cinnamon 2.2 running on debian 8. This should also work on Ubuntu, maybe the path is a bit different.

- open this file in an editor `/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/window-list@cinnamon.org/applet.js`
- find function `_getContentPreferredWidth: function(actor, forHeight, alloc)`
- change `alloc.natural_size = 150 * global.ui_scale;` to `alloc.natural_size = 350 * global.ui_scale;` where 350 is your desired width.

Good luck!

Comment: This works on Cinnamon 4.8.6. It's on line 648 on my version. This should really be a configuration option.